How to open the CMD or the PowerShell in the Windows terminal when you open them as Admin?
I noticed that when I open the CMD or the PowerShell in non-admin mode, it always opens in the terminal; however, when I open the CMD or the PowerShell as admin, it always opens the old window. Indeed, I can open the Terminal as admin, but I wonder why the CMD or the PowerShell as admin, doesn't open the Windows Terminal, but the old window instead.
Admin case:


Normal case:


You can run Windows Terminal as administrator, so, rather than opening "CMD" you search for Terminal and do the same thing. Have you tried this and does it work?

Also, is Admin a different user account on this computer, or are you running in your own local admin account that is the same account as your daily driver?

Windows Terminal also allows individual profiles to be set as Administrator, meaning you don't have to run Terminal itself as Administrator, but you can just open Terminal, and choose an Administrator profile.

Open Terminal (wt.exe) AS Administrator :
- Taskbar
Pin wt.exe to Taskbar, then Shift + Right Click > Run as Administrator

- Script
# openwtadmin.ps1
# select profil betwen
$prof = 'PowerShell'
#$prof = 'Windows PowerShell'
Start -Verb RunAs -FilePath "wt.exe" -argumentlist "-p `"$prof`""

If You want to run script elevated thought Terminal, add script below at top of your script.
It's will automatically:

get admin elevated
run in Terminal (if installed)
prefer to pwsh.exe (powershel 7xx if installed)

# set default console to WT.exe       (if installed)
# set default commandline to PWSH.exe (if installed)
# Replace $True with $False to disable
$RuninWT   = $True
$PreferPS7 = $True

$IsWT = where.exe wt.exe 2>$null
$HVM  = (Host).Version.Major
if ( $HVM -eq 7 -and $PreferPS7 ) {
    $p = 'pwsh.exe';       $prof = 'PowerShell'
} else {
    $p = 'powershell.exe'; $prof = 'Windows PowerShell'
}

if ( (fltmc).Count -eq 3 ) {
    if ( $IsWT -and $RuninWT ) {
        $arg1 = "-d `"$PSScriptRoot`" -p `"$prof`"", "cmd /c $p -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File `"$PSCommandPath`""
        Start -Verb RunAs -FilePath "wt.exe" -ArgumentList $arg1;
        taskkill.exe /f /im $PID; exit 0
    } else {
        $arg2 = "-NoProfile", "-ExecutionPolicy Bypass", "-File `"$PSCommandPath`""
        Start -Verb RunAs -FilePath $p -ArgumentList $arg2; exit 0
    }
}

'Your Script Here'
pause 

